# SQL Server stored procedure with subquery Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have four tables:

1. **SalesPerson** (`personId int ,PersonName nvarchar(20)`..)
2. **personAndDistrict** (`autoId int,PersonId int,districtId int`):every sales man working in a specific district(s)
3. **PointOfSales** (`SalesId int,pointOfSalesId int,districtId int,pointOfSalesName nvarchar(20)`,...) every district has many pointOfSales'.
4. **DailySales** (`SalesPersonId int,SoldAmount float,PointOfSalesId int, salesDate date`,..):Daily Sales data.

To save the daily sales for every sales person I need first to show a list for his all points of sales with **sum** (if any) of sold amount for each.

So, what we need is to show all Point Of Sales for a specific salesperson for a specific date with the total sold Amount for points.

I have the stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_PoinOfSales_GetDataForEntry]
      @SalesPersonId   int=null, @SalesDate  date=null
AS
   SELECT DISTINCT 
       par.SalesPersonId, 
       pos.pointOfsalesID, 
       pos.pointOfSalesName, 
       ISNULL((SELECT SUM(SoldAmount) AS Expr1 
               FROM   
                  dbo.DailySales AS ds 
               WHERE  
                  (SalesDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @salesDate, 102)) 
                  AND (SalesPersonId = par.SalesPersonId)  
                  AND (PointOfsalesID = ps.PointOfsalesID)), 0) AS SoldAmount, 
   FROM   
       dbo.PointOfSales AS pos 
   INNER JOIN 
       dbo.PersonAndDistrict AS par ON pos.districtId = par.districtId 
   WHERE  
       (@SalesPersonId IS NULL 
        OR par.SalesPersonId = @SalesPersonId ) 
   GROUP BY 
       pos.districtId, 
       pos.pointOfSalesName, 
       pos.PointOfsalesID, 
       par.SalesPersonId 
   ORDER BY 
       pos.PointOfsalesID, 
       pos.districtId
```

to return only 800 records (point's of sales) it take more than 6 seconds!

So, how to optimize this stored procedure to be executed within minimum time?

Comment: `@SalesPersonId IS NULL OR par.SalesPersonId = @SalesPersonId` will likely be sub optimal for the case that you *are* passing in a specific `SalesPersonId` (at least unless you are on 2008 and use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`). What indexes on the tables and what does the execution plan look like?

Comment: @Martin Smith forgot about the Parameter sniffing bug that's a nasty one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general way I find that inline views in a JOIN perform better than in the SELECT clause. So I would rewrite this way.

```
SELECT DISTINCT par.salespersonid, 
            pos.pointofsalesid, 
            pos.pointofsalesname, 
            Isnull(t.expr1, 0), 
            as soldamount 
FROM   dbo.pointofsales AS pos 
       INNER JOIN dbo.personanddistrict AS par 
         ON pos.districtid = par.districtid 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(soldamount) AS expr1, 
                         pointofsalesid, 
                         salespersonid 
                  FROM   dbo.dailysales AS ds 
                  WHERE  ( salesdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @salesDate, 102) ) 
                  GROUP  BY pointofsalesid, 
                            salespersonid) t 
         ON t.salespersonid = par.salespersonid 
            AND t.pointofsalesid = pos.pointofsalesid 
WHERE  ( @SalesPersonId IS NULL 
          OR par.salespersonid = @SalesPersonId ) 
GROUP  BY pos.districtid, 
          pos.pointofsalesname, 
          pos.pointofsalesid, 
          par.salespersonid 
ORDER  BY pos.pointofsalesid, 
          pos.districtid
```

Another choice is to move to a CTE below but that's mostly a style thing unless the Inline view is repeated in the SQL code.

```
WITH t 
     AS (SELECT SUM(soldamount) AS expr1, 
                pointofsalesid, 
                salespersonid 
         FROM   dbo.dailysales AS ds 
         WHERE  ( salesdate = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @salesDate, 102) ) 
         GROUP  BY pointofsalesid, 
                   salespersonid) 
SELECT DISTINCT par.salespersonid, 
                pos.pointofsalesid, 
                pos.pointofsalesname, 
                Isnull(t.expr1, 0) AS soldamount, 
FROM   dbo.pointofsales AS pos 
       INNER JOIN dbo.personanddistrict AS par 
         ON pos.districtid = par.districtid 
       LEFT JOIN t 
         ON t.salespersonid = par.salespersonid 
            AND t.pointofsalesid = pos.pointofsalesid 
WHERE  ( @SalesPersonId IS NULL 
          OR par.salespersonid = @SalesPersonId ) 
GROUP  BY pos.districtid, 
          pos.pointofsalesname, 
          pos.pointofsalesid, 
          par.salespersonid 
ORDER  BY pos.pointofsalesid, 
          pos.districtid
```

Comment: First option won't parse I think because of `GROUP`ing errors - `expr1` isn't in the `GROUP BY`.  The `ORDER BY` will also fail since `districtid` isn't in the select list.  The `ORDER BY` issue is present in the OP's code, though.

Comment: @JNK doh. Thanks I always drop the GROUP BY clause on those if I don't use Instant SQL Formatter. I also messed up some commas and parens. But you can order by somthing that's not in the select as long as its in the group by. [I wasn't sure myself so I tested it](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65732/order-by-and-group-by-but-not-in-select)

Comment: @conrad..Thanks, I selected the first option with some modification, plus (the grouping and orderby as mentioned by @JNK),

Comment: Happy that it works now (since the answer is accepted), but what kind of performance do you now get out of it + did you do anything else ? (like adding indexes)

Comment: @deroby- thanks, actually I added  indexes (soldamount,SalesDate), I accept conrad answer as a good change for sub-query, the performance is better but still low!